# Limit of Heat that can be transferred by refrigeration cycle

Tags: thermodynamics

I am a high school student, and have recently learned about Carnot Engine and refrigeration cycle. From what I understand, if an heat engine works between two reservoirs at different temperatures, it's efficiency has an upper limit, i.e., a maximum value.

So, if I fix the value of output work, the heat(input) necessary to do that work would have a lower limit.

Now, the refrigeration cycle would just be the reverse heat engine. So, for the fixed value of work, the heat that it can remove from room would also have a lower limit. Which implies that even if the work is less, we can theoretically extract a huge amount of heat from room.

But this is obviously wrong (as we would be transferring heat from colder object to hotter object without any work). I couldn't figure out where my reasoning is wrong though.

Comment: When you "reverse" your heat engine, you also need to reverse your constraint.

Comment: Oh yeah, that is where I went wrong. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, for the fixed value of work, the heat that it can remove from room
> would also have a lower limit.

Actually, for a fixed amount of heat removed there is a lower limit to the amount of work required based on the COP of the refrigerator.

> Which implies that even if the work is less, we can theoretically
> extract a huge amount of heat from room.

The coefficient of performance (COP) of a refrigerator is COP = $Q_{L}/W$. So for a given COP, if the work $W$ is less the heat removed $Q_L$ must also be less.

> But this is obviously wrong (as we would be transferring heat from
> colder object to hotter object without any work). I couldn't figure
> out where my reasoning is wrong though.

I think your reasoning went wrong with your first statement above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you recommend some text for my level to understand this topic better?

Comment: @PrerakContractor Check out Michael Moran's "Fundamentals
of Engineering Thermodynamics". I was able to download it free from the internet. Chapt 10 of my edition covers Refrigeration.